# iOS DispatchQueue.main.sync not working Swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: swift4, ios11, xcode9, dispatch-queue

I am trying to get TouchID to authenticate an action on my app. I need it to show an ImageView if successful.

Here is the code that I have in the ViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var notificationImage: UIImageView!
@IBAction func touchBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {    
    context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Authenticate"
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in
             if success {
                 print("In closure")
                 // Move to the main thread because a state update triggers UI changes.
                 DispatchQueue.main.async{
                     print("In main thread: Success")
                     self.notificationImage.isHidden = false
                  }
              } else {
                  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                      print("In main thread: Failed")
                  })
              }    
          }
      }
}
```

I am able to successfully authenticate using TouchID. It prints "In closure". But the block in the DispatchQueue.main.async does not execute and I am unable to update the notificationImage: UIImageView. Neither does it print anything in the sync{} blocks.

I have tried to disable Main Thread Checker and removing the DispatchQueue.main.async part, but the view sometimes refreshes and sometimes it doesn't. I want to use the recommended practice and update the UI from the main thread.

I am on Xcode 9 Swift 4 iOS 11.4

What could be wrong here.

Comment: change DispatchQueue.main.sync to DispatchQueue.main.async in if success.

Comment: @SureshDurishetti I’ve tried that too. Doesn’t work. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Is something else blocking the main thread? My Touch ID is almost identical except I pass the success to a delegate function and dispatch to main thread from there. But that shouldn't have any impact.

Comment: @BenAvery I’ll check this. But I don’t have anything else on the main thread. Even if there was, isn’t the Dispatcher supposed to make sure that the task is executed.

Comment: I checked this but nothing was happening on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  @IBAction func touchBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
        let reason = "Authenticate"
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in
            if success {
                do {
                    print("In closure")
                    print("In main thread: Success")
                    self.notificationImage.isHidden = false

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    print(error.description)
                }

            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    print("In main thread: Failed")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I get an error - Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread. This is the situation I wanted to avoid using eh Dispatcher. But somehow that seems to be misbehaving.